# R Script : How to keep the original format

Tags: r

I'm new to R and struggling abit with R auto convert my text string to number and this removed the ' 0 ' in some of my text.

I noticed this happened when i read in my txt file;

```
dataTheFlash <- read.csv(
  paste(strWF,"B_Allen_Is.txt",sep=""),  
  header = TRUE,
  sep=";",
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE
)
```

Is there anything i can do to keep my original content?

Many Thanks

Comment: Re-export your data and place quotes around the string number column.  Then R will parse them as strings.

Comment: Take a look at `?read.csv`, in particular the `colClasses` argument. In RStudio you can use the "import dataset" dialog and choose column class interactively.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify which columns you want to keep as characters using the `colClasses` argument to `read.csv`.

```
dataTheFlash <- read.csv(
  paste(strWF,"B_Allen_Is.txt",sep=""),  
  header = TRUE,
  sep=";",
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
  colClasses = c('name_of_column'='character')
)
```